# unix- show the second line of the file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

this command displays the second line of the file :

```
cat myfile | head -2 | tail -1
```

My file contains the following data :

```
hello
mark
this is the head line
this is the first line 
this is the second line 
this is the last line
```

the command above prints the data as: `mark`

But i am unable to understand this because, head -2 is used to print the first two lines and tail  -1 prints the last line but how come 2nd line is printed!!???

Comment: tail is only operating on the output from head, and `tail -1` means print the last line of output received. In this context (in a pipeline), `tail` doesn't know that myfile exists. Your pipeline is working as designed, and what you observe is considered a feature! ;-). Good luck.

Comment: I do not understand what is difficult to understand here?  It is the basic functionnality of the "|": directs the output of the left hand command to the input of the right hand command.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

tail displays the last line of the head output and the last line of the head output is the second line of the file.

Output of head (input to tail):

```
hello
mark
```

Output of tail:

```
mark
```

Answer (score 44):

You can also use "sed" or "awk" to print a specific line:

EXAMPLE:

```
sed -n '2p' myfile
```

PS:
As to "what's wrong with my 'head|tail'" command - shelltel is correct.

Comment: Well sed.  For efficiency on large files, I'd suggest `'2p;3q'` or `2{p;q;}` or similar.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `sed` command. Following are ways you could print the line number, you may select as per your task.

```
sed -n '2p' filename #get the 2nd line and prints the value (p stands for print)

sed -n '1,2p' filename #get the 1 to 2nd line and prints the values

sed -n '1p;2p;' filename #get the 1st and 2nd line values only
```

Answer (score 2):

If you break up operations into separate commands, it will become obvious why it works the way it works.

head -2 creates a file of two lines.

```
linux> head -2 /tmp/x > /tmp/xx
linux> cat /tmp/xx  
hello
mark
```

tail -1 prints out the last line in the file.

```
linux> tail -1 /tmp/xx
mark
```